# Adding random numbers but keep constant std

Tags: statistics, random-variables

If you keep adding random numbers, like this:

```
let x = 0;
for (i in 0..nRounds) {
  x = x + rand()
}
result = x / nRounds
```

The standard deviation of `result` will approach 0 as `nRounds` goes to infinity. Is there any way to modify this so that the standard deviation remains constant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Divide by the square root of nRounds instead of nRounds at the end.  The standard deviation of the sum is proportional to the square root of nRounds.